# Google Sheets, formula, reference to variable sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Google says in their web help how to reference data from another sheet, but what happens if what I need is to make the reference depending on my fields on the current sheet?

Let's say I have a sheet named 'Sheet1' and a sheet named 'Sheet2'. And on my current sheet (results) I have a column where I'll place the name of each sheet:

On Cell A1 value is: Sheet1
On Cell A2 value is: Sheet2
and so.

I want to have Cell B1 to get some data from the sheet quoted in A1 (i.e.Sheet1): `=Sheet1!$AC$1`

I want to have Cell B2 to get some data from the sheet quoted in A2 (i.e.Sheet2): `=Sheet2!$AC$1`

...and so on (for that, I need to copy down the formula with reference to column A content, to say, the corresponding sheet)

In summary: the formula should include reference to a VARIABLE sheet.
I've tried with both `=concatenate()` and also with `=indirect()` but no success...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Let say that A1 has the sheet name and that we want to reference A1 of that sheet. The formula will be:

```
=INDIRECT(A1&"!A1")
```

**Related Q&A**

- [Selecting a sequence of sheets in Google Docs / Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37642/88163)
- [Dynamically Building Array Of Sheet Names From A Range Of Cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104510/88163)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is yes:

- cell **B1**: **`=INDIRECT(A1 & "!$AC$1")`**
- cell **B2**: **`=INDIRECT(A2 & "!$AC$1")`**