# Reference same cell from multiple worksheets automatically with list going down?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I was wondering how can I make my main /master sheet more automatic so I don't have to input every data such as `=sheet1!b2`, `=sheet2!b2`, etc. I was thinking if there is some way to make it more automatic so whenever I create a new sheet it will update it on my master page with data of specific cells such as `b2` in every sheet.

I have found a way to automatically add sheet name into column:

```
function GetAllSheetNames() {
    var out = new Array()
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
    return out 
}
```

But I have no idea and could not find online how to make it so it makes list/column of data from every sheet `b2` cell.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I think you need to create a formula that combines a sheet name and a reference to cell B2. Have you read [Google Sheets, formula, reference to variable sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/117822/196152)?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you it works as i wanted! `=INDIRECT(A7&"!b18")` where a7 is the name of the sheet and b18 is the cell i want to reference to from that sheet